# Book about a banker/businessman going into a fantasy world, where he meets and falls in love with a plant girl

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai

I read this book like 15-18 years ago in middle school.

I think it starts with a banker or businessman finding a coin, I think, and going into a fantasy world, where he meets and falls in love with a plant girl. If memory serves, they had children together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [the first book in the Landover series by Terry Brooks - "Magic Kingdom for Sale-SOLD"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Kingdom_for_Sale%E2%80%94Sold!).

A bored businessman sees an advert with this title in the paper; and buys the kingdom. He is transported to Landover, and after many adventures, marries a sylph.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it!!!!